# Corpus with many elements to dataframe and then save in csv

Tags: r, csv, corpus

I have a set of 9 csv files and I use the commands below to import them and do some data preprocessing:

```
library(tm)
filenames <- list.files(getwd(),pattern=”*.txt”)
files <- lapply(filenames,readLines)
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(files))
```

Then i removed stop words.

Now, I have a corpus with 9 elements. I need to save them in 9 separate CSV files.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `writeCorpus(docs)` to write your corpus to 9 separate `.txt` files. You can consequently convert these to `.csv` if you like.